# Is it possible to split an array across multiple cells with PHPExcel?

Tags: mysql, arrays, excel, phpexcel

I've managed to create a page which generates a Excel file from a MySQL database. Three of the columns in this data table contain an array. My question is: is it possible to split this array and divide it over cells among each other? My Excel sheet looks like this:
[image]

And I want it to look like this:
[image]

I hope that you know what I mean, and if someone maybe knows a solution for this or got an idea on how I might possible achieve this that would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No! PHPExcel doesn't have any magic to interpret your array; that's something you need to code yurself

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer! @MarkBaker